# Get the BIOS time in LINGO

Tags: bios, lingo

Can someone tell me how to get the BIOS time in Lingo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_system.time() will give you the system time.
You can also use the good old Lingo syntaxed "the systemDate" wich is an object with properties such as ".seconds" for example.

To access the BIOS probably need a custom built xtra. You can build one in Delphi or C/C++ but to make it auto-downloadable you need to sign if i remember correctly (Long time since I made one). :-)